# css3 media query that actually validates as css3?

Tags: css, media-queries, retina-display

This is driving me nuts - who has a css3 media query that actually validates as css3? I've tried several, including Chris Coyier's, with no luck, and I'm validating here:

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

I've made sure I'm validating under css3, too. What am I missing?

*Edited to add:*

Here's the code I'm putting in the validator, verbatim from Chris' site:

```
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```

Here's the error the validator gives:

Feature -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio doesn't exist for media null ), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { /* Retina-specific stuff here */ }

Comment: What are the notices/errors it's giving you? What's your CSS look like?

Comment: Media queries ARE valid CSS3.  You must be misunderstanding the validation errors.  It's not possible for us to help you without seeing your code... also W3C validation is not the be-all end-all of everything, sometimes invalid code is a necessity (vendor prefixes, graceful degradation etc).

Comment: I've just added the details of the code and error. Any insight from this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a vendor prefix in the Media feature: -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio. CSS properties with prefixes validate in the CSS validator (there is a setting to make them errors or warnings), but media features don't. This is probably a bug in the validator.